# PHP works on web but not on local apache (linux mint)

Tags: php, linux, apache, localhost

I tried to run [PHP form tutorial](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-tutorial.html) on local apache,
while it works on my web apache it won't work on local.
In my local machine I get the following error:

> "Notice: Undefined index: formSubmit in /opt/lampp/htdocs/rw/form/myform1.php on line 2".

I have appended the lampp user and group and tried to set privileges from 644 to 777 with no result. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alex,
It is not an error. That is just a `notice`, kind of "warning". It is because the php.ini settings in you local machine is set to show you notices, along with `errors`.
You could check if that value has been `set`, in order to avoid that notice.
To do that, you can use `isset()`:

> isset() function in PHP determines whether a variable is set and is
>   not NULL. It returns a Boolean value, that is, if the variable is set
>   it will return true and if the variable value is null it will return
>   false.

**Ref:** http://notesofgenius.com/how-fix-php-notice-undefined-index/

**To hide notices:**
Now you have a `php.ini` setting `error_reporting` set to include `E_NOTICE`. You can choose not to show notices by setting `error_reporting` to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`

Answer (score 2):

Check that the variable is set before getting it from array :

```
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']) && $_POST['formSubmit'])
```

Comment: Thanx, error dissapear, but now I have somethnig inside cells <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: varMovie in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/rw/form/myform1.php</b> on line <b>46</b><br />  .??